# How do i set cell.accessoryType to an image?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to set the cell accessory type to my own custom image

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
cell?.accessoryType = UIImage(named: "heart.pdf")
```

How would i do that in Swift?

Regards

Comment: `cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "heart.pdf"))`? But you might want to resize a little the imageView before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add your own image with the help of accessoryView of table view cell as below.

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)    
let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
imgView.image = UIImage(named: "{your image name}")!
cell.accessoryView = imgView
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set accessory type by setting cell accessory View like this:

```
    // first create UIImageView
    var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 320))// change your height/width as per your needs.
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage.jpg")

    //then set it as cellAccessoryType
    yourCell.accessoryView = imageView
```

Comment: You are calling twice an init on `imageView`. Either do `var imageView = UIImageView(); imageView.frame = ...` or `var imageView = UIImageView(frame: ...)`. I'd tend to use an 0,0 origin too, no?

Comment: @Larme, Thanks for the valuable inputs! I edited my answer accordingly. :)